# Symfony2 Forms: How do I create a collection of 'entity' forms

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a one to many unidirectional relationship in my model. A `User` has one of many `Status`.

Using doctrine these are mapped as a unidirectional many-to-many with a unique constraint on one of the join columns.

I'd like to use a symfony form to select a status from the status table, submit the form and have symfony persist the relationship.

I've tried two approaches:

1. Using the Entity form type, however this produces an error (due to the many-to-many relationship doctrine expects to receive an instance of `ArrayCollection` rather than a single status object.
2. Using a collection entity objects. When using this approach an empty div with the id `status` is rendered in the form. Where as I expected a select box to appear containing status options.

Here is the code. Where am I wrong?

Entity code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Status")
 */
protected $status;
```

Form type code:

```
 $builder->add('status', 'collection', array(
     'type' => 'entity',
     'allow_add' => true,
     'options' => array(
         'class' => 'SunflyCoreBundle:Status',
         'property' => 'name',
         ))
 );
```

Form template code:

```
<form action="{{ path('_product_create_process') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
  {{ form_widget(form) }} 
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

HTML Rendered on the page:

```
<div id="product_status" data-prototype="STUFF THAT WONT RENDER ON SO"></div>
```

Comment: The use of the 'collection' type isn't appropriate in this case, you really do need the entity type. Would it be possible to use a Data Transformer (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to convert your single status to/from an ArrayCollection?

Comment: Mmmmmh can you clarify:  A `User` has one of many `Status` != `these are mapped as a unidirectional many-to-many`. Why are you doing this??

Comment: Cheesemacfly - If that isn't the way forward could you show me which of the relationships are most appropriate? I'm working from the Doctrine 2 docs - [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)

Comment: A `User` can have one, and only one `Status` at a time right? And a `Status` can have as many `User` as possible right? So you should use a One-To-Many relationship. See the example here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: Your absolutely correct, this soved my problem. If you put an answer in I'll accept it?